# Is it possible to establish multiple vpn connections with node.js?

Tags: node.js, vpn

Is is possible to establish 3 OpenVPN connections, each one on different port, at the same time, send requests and get responses with each one of them?

What node packages would I need to achieve this?

Comment: You can set node to listen to multi ports yes

Comment: Could I connect to multiple VPNs at once? @Eric

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js - Programmatically Connect to a VPN or route HTTP Requests via VPN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048832/node-js-programmatically-connect-to-a-vpn-or-route-http-requests-via-vpn)

Comment: This q&a explains how to set up one VPN connection in Ubuntu and use it programmatically with cURL or something else: https://serverfault.com/questions/992624/vpn-client-doesnt-have-internet-connection