# Route node.js requests through a VPN

Tags: node.js, routes, request, network-programming, vpn

So am doing some webscraping and i would like to be able to get my current public ip adresse (am using a vpn) , using request module to retrieve it from an api (ipify.org) , the problem is that it always return my "real" ip adresse instead of the current vpn ip adresse , which means that the requests do not go through the vpn tunnel layer , is that possible to force it ? i found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048832/node-js-programmatically-connect-to-a-vpn-or-route-http-requests-via-vpn) but the answer wasn't really helping me enough

Comment: A typical VPN will run on your system and route the traffic automatically. You would need to provide a lot more details on your configuration. What you can do on a programming level is use a proxy, as pointed by the link you provided.

Comment: Also if your question is about VPN, it's likely better asked on another SO website like "SuperUser". You're dealing with some apparently incorrect VPN configuration. If your question is about how to get Node.js to use a proxy, then this would likely be the right place.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ... and no , i do not want to use a proxy , the vpn route perfectly the traffic but not node.js requests , as you said i may want to ask on the SO site , thank you again.